# JobTracker doesn't show completed tasks

Tags: hadoop, configuration

I am running `hadoop-1.1.2` on my laptop in pseudo-distributed mode. I am able to run a simple WordCount program, reading from and writing back to `HDFS`. I am also able to see `JobTracker` running at `http://localhost:50030/jobtracker.jsp`. However when I run the WordCount job from Eclipse, there is no entry, either under running or completed jobs.

Am I missing any additional property setting in one of the configuration files?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because when you are running your job through Eclipse it starts running job inside itself rather than submitting it to the JobTracker as it does not know where to go to find the JobTracker. You need to tell it to Eclipse. Add the following lines in your code and it should work :

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
conf.set("fs.default.name", "hdfs://localhost:9000");
conf.set("mapred.job.tracker", "localhost:9001");
```

Comment: Thanks. Does that mean that one has to set again in Eclipse all the properties set in the .xml files in the conf directory of `$HADOOP_INSTALL`?

Comment: No. Why would you do that?

Comment: I do not understand. If Eclipse could not pick up the JobTracker location from the .xml configuration files, would it also not pick up any other properties set in those configuration files?

Comment: Once Eclipse knows where to find NN and JT it will get rest of the info from them. And actually the client doesn't have to worry about anything once the job has been submitted to JT. It is the job of JT to find TT machines having the data block with free slots and start the processing.

Answer (score 0):

Copy your hdfs-site.xml and mapred-site.xml into your 'src' folder (make them available in classpath).
It will pick up all Configurations.